# Why does EF throw an exception here?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Ok i'm going nuts here, I have been trying to write myself an update method in my repository and for some strange reason I get an exception when I call this ...

```
public virtual T Update(T entity)
{
    T dbEntity = _context.Set<T>().Find(entity.GetId());

    if (dbEntity != null)
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return dbEntity;
}
```

The exception occurs on "_context.SaveChanges();", context in this case is a DbContext instance as opposed to an object context. I'm using EF code first and the of T is as follows ...

```
public partial class AC_Programme
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime AutoCalculationTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime AutoCutoffTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AC_Fund> AC_Funds { get; set; }

    public virtual CX_Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

I can't understand why despite having done literally nothing, all I did was retrieve an object by id and call save changes, that it feels the need to go messing with relationships.

Any Ideas?

EDIT: oops I forgot to include the exception ...

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. 
>       When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. 
>       If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

It gets even more peculiar ...

```
    public virtual T Update(T entity)
    {
       _context.SaveChanges();
        return null;
    }
```

... results in the same error.

Comment: What is the thrown exception? You haven't posted it

Comment: the exception object contains a ValidationErrors property. This is a good place to start to find out why the exception occurs

Comment: My bad sorry about the missing exception info ... Its there now.

Comment: I think you have problem somewhere else. When you call `SaveChanges()` entire tracked entities are saved. Maybe one of them don't meet EF validation roles.

Comment: Nothing else is changing, literally nothing else, this is behind a webapi odata controller that receives a json instance of that same entity and passes it to this method which then does exactly as shown.

Comment: comment the ` T dbEntity = _context.Set<T>().Find(entity.GetId());` line and check if same exception is thrown or not.

Comment: huh that's even more strange - added outcome to question.

Comment: Add some debug logging before the `SaveChanges` call of what's in `_context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` to determine what you've changed somehow.

Comment: hmmm interesting ... there are 3 items in there 2 modified and 1 unchanged. Is there a way i can track where these have come from?

Comment: Thanks @johnnyHK ... just the bit of information I needed. I walked back up the stack and found that the AutoMapper profile was mapping from the posted DTO to the actual entity (not intended & not what I thought was happening) ... got it working by telling it to map to a new instance of the entity instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that some code further up the stack was adding changes in to EF that should not have been there causing this problem.

Diagnosing this problem was possible by putting a breakpoint on the SaveChanges call and examining "_context.ChangeTracker.Entries()" for changes then looking through the call stack to see what was going on.

Depending on the complexity of your own code if faced with this you may find it beneficial to add the change tracker to the watch window then step through the code until a change appears.

Thanks for the advice @JohnnyHK

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exception I'm assuming you forgot to set the value of a property which is part of a foreign key constraint; maybe `OrganizationId`?

Another possibility is that you removed a child entity from `AC_Funds` property and did not mark the child as deleted. This would result in an orphaned child which means setting the foreign key property to a null value.

Since your foreign key does not allow nulls the child entity cannot be orphaned and must be deleted.

I would suggest opening the Sql Server Profiler and peeking at the update statements generated by Entity Framework.

Comment: No value type properties are null ... but thats moot point since I didn't actually update anything ... if you read the code, I get an entity from the db then call SaveChanges on the context, nothing else is done.

Comment: @Wardy, something must have been changed. Try taking a look under the hood with Sql Server Profiler.

Comment: hooked up profiler to sql and this is all that was run ... exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[OrganisationId] AS [OrganisationId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Start] AS [Start], 
    [Extent1].[End] AS [End], 
    [Extent1].[Active] AS [Active], 
    [Extent1].[AutoCalculationTime] AS [AutoCalculationTime], 
    [Extent1].[AutoCutoffTime] AS [AutoCutoffTime]
    FROM [ACOFI].[AC_Programme] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=1

Comment: I would expect this to be the case as I only made 1 other call (the find by id call in the same method).

Comment: @Wardy, the query above does not alter the data. There should be an update statement somewhere in the profiler.

Comment: There's no updates or inserts at all in the profiler ... i don't think this is a SQL issue I think it's somewhere in EF, I somehow have a change or something in there that it doesn't like and thus won't even attempt to go near the db.